# How to check if Contact has Image?

Tags: android

I am assigning to an ImageView contacts images using this code:

```
mPhotoView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
mPhotoView.setImageURI(objItem.getPhotoUri());
```

If the contact has no image, this does nothing, and no error is raised.

When there is no image, I want to add a default image. So I need to check either if the image was added to the view, or check that the URI holds some image data

How do I achieve that?

Than I will set default image by this:

```
mPhotoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture_2);
```

Comment: are you targeting eclair or cupcake/donut?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your target device is running android 2.0/2.0.1/2.1 you will have to query [ContactsContract.Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html).CONTENT_URI with a selection like:

```
Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
```

Otherwise query [Contacts.Photos](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.Photos.html).CONTENT_URI

**Edit by Pentium10**

For reference I include here the method I come up with (if you still see bugs, update it):

```
public Uri getPhotoUri() {
    Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(getId()));
    Uri photo = Uri.withAppendedPath(person,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

    Cursor cur = this.ctx
            .getContentResolver()
            .query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                            + "="
                            + this.getId()
                            + " AND "
                            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
                            + "='"
                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                            + "'", null, null);
    if (cur != null) {
        if (!cur.moveToFirst()) {
            return null; // no photo
        }
    } else {
        return null; // error in cursor process
    }
    return photo;
}
```

Comment: This is not a detailed explanation, but if you are familiar with ContentProviders/ContentResolvers this should be enough. Otherwise let me know and I'll post some code examples.

Comment: Thank you. I edited your answer and included the solution I come up with. Check for bugs.

Comment: for some reason , some times if contact has more detail, return uri, but uri have no image

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, there may be another(better?) option. If you have a cursor of all contacts and you're say, binding them to a listview, you can simply attempt to retrieve a photo using openContactPhotoInputStream, and check for null.

```
InputStream stream = Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(), lookupUri);
if (stream == null) {
    //your logic here when no photo found
}
```

Here's a quick example for any who may stumble upon this :

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;

//Define someDefaultPhoto somewhere accessible

protected Bitmap getContactPhoto(Context context, Uri lookupUri) {
    Bitmap resultPhoto;
    InputStream stream;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        //For some reason this seems to be necessary pre-ICS. If anyone knows why, I'd love to hear
        lookupUri = Contacts.lookupContact(context.getContentResolver(), lookupUri);
    }
    stream = Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(context.getContentResolver(), lookupUri);

    if (stream == null) {
        resultPhoto = someDefaultPhoto;
    }
    else {
        resultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
    }
    return resultPhoto;
}
```

Then you can call it with something like this:

```
int columnLookupKey = cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY);
String lookupKey = cursor.getString(columnLookupKey);
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
Bitmap contactPhoto = getContactPhoto(context, lookupUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with based on the other answers.

```
    private Uri getUserPictureUri(long id) {
        Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
        Uri picUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(person,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        try {
            InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(picUri);
            is.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return picUri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the PHOTO_ID column in PhoneLookUp Content provider is null or not
Here is a method I've developed:

```
public static boolean hasContactPhoto(Context context, String number) {
    String thumbUri = "";
    String photoId = "";
    String id = "";
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(number));
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
            new String[] {ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID,ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.PHOTO_ID}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
        photoId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.PHOTO_ID));
    }
    cursor.close();
    if(!id.equals("") && photoId != null && !photoId.equals(""))
        return true;
        //sms.setContactThumb(ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(id)).toString());
    else
        return false;
}
```

if you need the contact image uri get it from:

> ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(id)).toString()

and if you need to set it to an image view use the following line (I've used Universal Image Loader 1.9.2 for image loading purposes):

> ```
>         ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(currentRecord.getContactThumb(),viewHolder.mThumbIV);
> ```

note : contactThumb is the **last described uri**
Cheers!