# how to set a image based on contact

Tags: android

I am beginner to android. Now I am trying to create an application to set a image based on contact. Please help me to do it. I want to know the steps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if Contact has Image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480312/how-to-check-if-contact-has-image)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480312/how-to-check-if-contact-has-image).

You can use [setImageUri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI%28android.net.Uri%29) to display the image at the resulting `Uri` in your `ImageView`.